# Converting string (with list of list) to list

Tags: python, string, list

I need to convert a string which has nested lists in it, into a list
Is there a way to do this without the use of eval() and non standard python libraries?
An example would be:

```
input = '[4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,10]],11,12,[13,14]]'
output = [4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,10]],11,12,[13,14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert the string

> without the use of eval() and non standard python libraries

you could make use of [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), which is part of the Python Standard Library:

```
import json

input_as_string = '[4,[5,6],7,[8,[9,10]],11,12,[13,14]]'
input_as_list = json.loads(input_as_string)

print(input_as_list.__class__)
#=> <class 'list'>
```